# When shouldn't you use t(), st(), etc. with readable string literals?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Drupal coding standards [dictate](http://drupal.org/node/299085) that nearly all string literals should be passed through [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) or [`st()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!install.inc/function/st/7) for translation;  however there are some exceptions, such as titles in [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/hook_menu).  When isn't `t()` or `st()` necessary? I've posted a community wiki answer hoping people will edit it.

Comment: Not sure what the best link is to refer to for "run all strings through t()".

Comment: @MPD thanks for adding the links. I couldn't find a page on using `t()` in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Descriptions and titles in `hook_menu()` *
2. Descriptions in `hook_schema()` **
3. `watchdog()` messages *
4. Field/instance definition labels and descriptions ***

* potx extracts the strings
** don't get translated
*** can be translated with contrib, eg. i18n_field